# Storing arraylist into another arraylist in c#

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I want to insert productDetail  arraylist in products arraylist

> ArrayList products = new ArrayList();
>
> ArrayList productDetail = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
>    foreach (DataRow myRow in myTable.Rows)
>      {
>      productDetail.Clear();                      
>       productDetail.Add( "CostPrice" + "," + myRow["CostPrice"].ToString());
>
>       products.Insert(myTable.Rows.IndexOf(myRow),(object)productDetail);
>      }
> ```

**But each entery in  product list is filled with last productdetails ArrayList.**
*What wrong I am doing here?*

Comment: What does `myTable.Rows.IndexOf(myRow)` return on each iteration?

Comment: It returns the index of foreach loop.

Comment: You want to add the ArrayList as a whole or its last item? Can you be more clear about that you are trying to do

Comment: Try `products.Add((object)productDetail);` instead of `Insert`.

Comment: ArrayList is deprecated and shouldn't really be used if you can avoid it. Generics is useful here, in particular List<T>.

Comment: I was  always adding a reference to the same object that was problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving

```
ArrayList productDetail = new ArrayList();
```

inside the `foreach` loop:

```
ArrayList products = new ArrayList();
foreach (DataRow myRow in myTable.Rows) {
    ArrayList productDetail = new ArrayList();
    productDetail.Add( "CostPrice" + "," + myRow["CostPrice"].ToString());
    products.Insert(myTable.Rows.IndexOf(myRow),(object)productDetail);
}
```

The point is that, in your code, you are always adding a reference to the same object: `Insert` is not making a copy of your list each time...

Answer (score 1):

productDetails only ever has one item in it.
Your first step is `productDetail.Clear();` 
Move that outside the foreach to achieve your desired result.

```
    ArrayList products = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList productDetail = new ArrayList();

    productDetail.Clear(); 

       foreach (DataRow myRow in myTable.Rows)
         {

          productDetail.Add( "CostPrice" + "," + myRow["CostPrice"].ToString());

          products.Insert(myTable.Rows.IndexOf(myRow),(object)productDetail);
         }
```